# Event doesn't appear in the browser

Tags: jquery

So I'm trying to make a simple event handler using `.mouseenter` method, but it doesn't appear in the browser.

```html
    <body>
       <header>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="./home.html">Home</a> 
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="./project.html">Projects</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#About-Me">About Me</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="./contact.html">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </header>

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="./home.js"></script>
    </body>
<style>
    .effect {
        color: blue;
    }
</style>
<script>    
    $(document).ready(() => {
        $("li").on('mouseenter', (event) => {
            $(this).addClass('effect');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Nothing happens, I have the latest version of jQuery 3.4.1 first I taught that the problem was related with the .on function, because the browser kept repeating

> uncaught type error: 'li'.on is not a function.

but right now it simply doesn't run in my browser, and I´m not receiving any error message.

Can somebody help me please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this.

`$("li").on('mouseenter', function( ) {
      $(this).addClass('effect');
});`

Or with es6 you can use

`$("li").on('mouseenter', (event) => {
     $(event.currentTarget).addClass('effect');
});`

Comment: Worth noting that neither of them need to be wrapped in `$(document).ready`

Comment: I tried this way; 

$("li").on('mouseenter', (event) => {
     $(event.currentTarget).addClass('effect');
});

but nothing happened, it seems that when I write event.currentTarget my visual code studio text doesn't assume it, the letters don't change colors.

Answer (score 0):

It is simply because `$(this)` does not refer to your `li` tag, but the hole `window`. so it adds a class to the hole `window`, no error, not desired action. I think after you know this "Akhilesh's" answer is good and solves your problem.

Comment: I tried this way; 

$("li").on('mouseenter', (event) => {
     $(event.currentTarget).addClass('effect');
});

but nothing happened, it seems that when I write event.currentTarget my visual code studio text doesn't assume it, the letters don't change colors.

Comment: Make sure your browser is up to date and support es6.

Make sure your scripts are inside `<script>` tag.

You always can check which lines are executing by adding `console.log('something here')` to after or before that line.
Also in my VSCode `event.currentTarget`'s color is sky blue.
Let us know if you had any progress.

Comment: Ok Pouria it's solved, tried to use anonymous function instead of an arrow function and it works, t seems that event.currentTarget is not installed in my program.
Thanks for the help.